# Prevent error in Django template when getting width of an ImageField missing an image

Tags: django, django-templates, python-imaging-library

In Django, when I have an ImageField and want to output the width of it in a template I do:

```
{{ myimage.width }}
```

This works well if the image is found. However, if the image can not be found for some reason getting the width the page creates an error and the template will not render. This behavior makes sense, however, how do I make this fail gracefully? Meaning, I would like the template to output nothing for myimage.width if the image can not be found and be able to continue rendering the page.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Simply write

```
{% if myobject.image %}
    {{ myobject.image.width }}
{% endif %}
```

There will be nothing if image is None.

Comment: What about the IOError "No such file or directory"? For example, a path is set and the image was renamed or removed?

Comment: When image will be renamed, you will get 404, not exception. I just checked it.

Comment: UPD: exception will be raised is access `width` attribute. In this case if you need, you have to modify `ImageField` to not raise exception. Renaming file without modifying object is not normal situation.

Answer (score 0):

May be not your favourite solution: You can add a method get_my_image_width() to your model that contains the ImageField. This method check the existence of the image and return None oder '' in that case.

Or you subclass the ImageField class and return a dummy object instead of None if the image is not there. This dummy object can be like the following:

```
class Dummy(object):
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        return None
```